# Twitter Login Effect?

Tags: jquery, twitter

On twitter they have a login link and when js is enabled jquery shows the login box, and when it is disabled it just goes to the login page instead.

How do they change it into a link when javascript in disabled? Or unchange it from a link when js is enabled, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All they need to do is to change it *with* javascript. If javascript isn't enabled, the change doesn't occur.

Just create a simple link:

```
<a id="login-link" href="/Login">Log in</a>
```

And override its functionality with javascript:

```
$('#login-link').click(function() {
    showLoginBox();
    return false; // don't navigate to /Login
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You begin with a normal link, and use jQuery to transfrom that link into a login box. That's called [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) [enhancement](http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/02/progressive-enhancement-with-jquery-example/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/blah/blah/login" id="loginlink">Click me!</a>
<script>
    $('#loginlink').attr('href','#');
    $('#loginlink').click(function(event){
        // show login window here

        // prevent the default "click" event
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

I'm not making any guarantees how *they* do it, but this is how it could be done: if there's no JS, there's a normal link to login; if there's JS, remove the link's HREF and set it to show login box on click. [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) in action :)